# I can't seem to clone an array without the changes in one being reflected in the other. I've tried Object.assign, slice, Array,from, all to no avail

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

The title pretty much sums it up. I am receiving an array from an API call, and storing it in a variable called `this.ratesStore.aprRates`. I then want to create a *new* array with the same data in it, called `this.aprRates`. However, no matter how I try, whenever I modify data in the "cloned" array, the other one is affected as well.

I've tried cloning the array via Object.assing, slice, Array.from, and spread operator, but I get the same issue every single time.

For instance, trying this:

```
console.log('apr rates - before:', this.aprRates);
console.log('rates store apr rates - before:', this.ratesStore.aprRates[0].terms[0].rate);

this.aprRates = this.ratesStore.aprRates.slice(0);

console.log('apr rates - after:', this.aprRates[0].terms[0].rate);
this.aprRates[0].terms[0].rate = 'chickens';
console.log('rates store apr rates - after:', this.ratesStore.aprRates[0].terms[0].rate);
```

Yields this output for me:

```
apr rates - before: undefined
rates store apr rates - before: 1.89
apr rates - after: 1.89
rates store apr rates - after: chickens
```

Any idea why this is happening?? I'm losing my mind over here. I'm writing this as part of an Angular component, if that makes any difference.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to deep clone, not shallow clone

Comment: Hey, so, I figured it out. I'm making a shallow copy when I should be making a deep copy. Sorry if you wasted your time reading my question. Stay safe out there!